# Use Enum to infer type from interface

Tags: typescript

I have an enum ResourceType

```
enum ResourceType {
  Blog = "blogs",
  BlogAuthor = "blog_authors",
  [...]
}
```

And I have typings for all resource types which I store in an interface:

```
interface ResourceDefinitions {
  [ResourceType.Blog]: BlogResource;
  [ResourceType.BlogAuthor]: BlogAuthorResource;
  [...]
```

What I want `resource` to be typed as `BlogResource` in this code:

```
const resource = useResource(ResourceType.Blog, id);
```

Where `useResource` is

```
const useResource = <P extends ResourceType, T = ResourceDefinitions[P]>(
  type: P,
  id: string
): T => {
  [...]
};
```

However, `T = ResourceDefinitions[P]` raises `TS2536: Type 'P' cannot be used to index type 'ResourceDefinitions'.`.

Is there a way to do this?

Two working solutions which are not very pretty:

Type it manually everywhere in the code like this:

```
const useResource = <T>(
  type: ResourceType,
  id: string
): T => {
  [...]
};

const resource = useResource<BlogResource>(ResourceType.Blog, id);
```

Use keyof to type the resourceType manually

```
const useResource = <P extends keyof ResourceDefinitions, T = ResourceDefinitions[P]>(
  type: P,
  id: string
): T => {
  [...]
};

const resource = useResource(ResourceType.Blog as keyof ResourceDefinitions, id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `ResourceDefinitions` did not include all keys of the enum `ResourceType`, raising the error `ResourceType cannot be used to index type 'ResourceDefinitions'`. This was not clear from my question because I left out parts of the code. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it works fine when removing the superfluous generic return type:

```
type BlogResource = { b: 'b' };
type BlogAuthorResource = { ba: 'ba' };

enum ResourceType {
  Blog = "blogs",
  BlogAuthor = "blog_authors"
}

interface ResourceDefinitions {
  [ResourceType.Blog]: BlogResource;
  [ResourceType.BlogAuthor]: BlogAuthorResource;
}

const useResource = <P extends ResourceType>(
  type: P,
  id: string
): ResourceDefinitions[P] => {
  throw new Error();
};

const resource = useResource(ResourceType.Blog, ''); // inferred as BlogResource
```

---

<sup>[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAQgNgewOYCUIGcEFcBOBjaAXigG8oAjALigHJyaoBfAbgFgAoUSWRJAQSzAAFghxpMuAlGJlyAQ2p05DFhw4QAdlgC2UcdnwQAKuGgkOUHsmlQAROV7pbAGgtX+gkThv3eAfTlPUScORjV2AEsNYAgcADM5KX1JCAARCDioiOAIhA10UjcAbWTDE0gAOnhkAF1qatQMAwI2dksSppTyiCreAWFROvd+r1KW0PC8PPRgKCx0CDGiKAAeAAUoCAAPGI0AEwKl7oA+AAo3LghqNdc2qAi96hmcKKQOAEpqJfTMjWzc-JFNY1aTHQp3YQ4BAAdygGggsIAojgoThTu9Wqp2BwpvlZjhOoYbPNFoSCKcjqZeshnLQaBigA)</sup>